# using ordiellipse in NMDS in R on axes 2 and 3

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to apply NMDS by vegan package on a dataset by the following functions:

```
library(vegan)
library(MASS)
library(MVA)
library(ggplot2)
all_d <- vegdist(landmetr, method= "hor", binary=FALSE, diag=TRUE,
             upper=FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
allmds3 <- isoMDS(all_d, k=3)
gr0 <- factor(france100_7c$LAND_CODE)
plot(allmds3$points[,2:3], col=gr0, bg="grey", cex=0.2,pch=20) 
# regress environmental variables on configuration of site points
provaenv3 <- envfit(allmds3$points[,2:3], landmetr,999, na.rm = FALSE, france100_7c$LAND_CODE)
# add the environmental regressions to the area plot
plot(provaenv3,add=T, cex=0.5)
#plot0
ordiellipse (allmds3, gr0, kind = "sd", conf=0.95, label = T)
```

However, despite a this biplot is constructed on axes  2 and 3, the ordiellipse function write the ellipses which identify clusters on the axes 1 and 2 biplot.
Could anyone explain me why this happens and how could I plot the right ellipses on axes 2 and 3 biplot?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to `landmetr`. Can you make your example reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the alternative plot function `ordiplot()`:

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
NMDS <- metaMDS(dune, k = 3)
pl<-ordiplot(NMDS, choices = c(2, 3), display = 'sites', type = 'n')
points(pl, what = 'sites', col = dune.env$Management, pch = 16)
ordiellipse(pl, dune.env$Management)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, the intended usage would be to pass `choices` to `ordiellipse` too. As stated in `?ordiellipse`

```
 ...: Parameters passed to graphical functions or to ‘scores’ to
      select axes and scaling etc.
```

hence the example of @EDi could be done more simply by

```
library("vegan")
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
set.seed(1234)
NMDS <- metaMDS(dune, k = 3)
take <- c(1,3)
plot(NMDS, choices = take, display = "sites", type = "n")
points(NMDS, choices = take, display = "sites",
       col = dune.env$Management)
with(dune.env, ordiellipse(NMDS, Management, choices = take))
```

producing

[image]

Comment: +1.  Can the ellipses be colored by a factor? Currently, I think, ordiellipse (and others) accept only one color. Might be as useful feature (I always use a loop). If it's not possible I could try to implement it...